# Python: How to select the latest created file (Uploading Keras Checkpoints to GCS)

Tags: python, keras, glob

I'm using Keras and CheckPoint() callback to create a list of checkpoints in the following format:

```
- app
--script.py
--checkpoint.01-{model-loss}.h5
--checkpoint.02-{model-loss}.h5
--checkpoint.03-{model-loss}.h5
--checkpoint.02-{model-loss}.h5
...
--checkpoint.10-{model-loss}.h5
..
--checkpoint.99-{model-loss}.h5
--checkpoint.100-{model-loss}.h5
..
```

I define the checkpoints as:

```
model_path_glob = 'checkpoint.*'
checkpoints = glob.glob(model_path_glob) # gives me a list but in weird order
```

The above is executed in a loop, so `checkpoints` is continuously updated.
I can see that the `len(checkpoints)` changes correctly with every iteration, so they are all there, but in a weird order.

However, it seems that I'm uploading the same file to the server using `checkpoint[-1]`, for example the first 15 iterations will upload checkpoint 1,2,3,.. but then it will always select the 16th iteration.

On my local machine, it selects 99th iteration and doesn't go past it.

Answer (score 0):

`checkpoints = sorted(glob.glob(model_path_glob), key=os.path.getmtime)` will sort by last time modification. I'm yet to try on cloud VM